# Shorten code of JQUERY UI Slider with specific values

Tags: jquery

```
var values = [50000, 100000, 150000, 200000, 250000, 300000, 350000, 400000, 450000, 500000, 550000, 600000, 650000, 700000, 750000, 800000, 850000, 900000, 950000, 1000000, 1100000, 1200000, 1300000, 1400000, 1500000, 1600000, 1700000, 1800000, 1900000, 2000000, 2100000, 2200000, 2300000, 2400000, 2500000, 2600000, 2700000, 2800000, 2900000, 3000000, 3100000, 3200000, 3300000, 3400000, 3500000, 3600000, 3700000, 3800000, 3900000, 4000000, 4100000, 4200000, 4300000, 4400000, 4500000, 4600000, 4700000, 4800000, 4900000, 5000000, 5100000, 5200000, 5300000, 5400000, 5500000, 5600000, 5700000, 5800000, 5900000, 6000000, 6100000, 6200000, 6300000, 6400000, 6500000, 6600000, 6700000, 6800000, 6900000, 7000000, 7100000, 7200000, 7300000, 7400000, 7500000, 7600000, 7700000, 7800000, 7900000, 8000000, 8100000, 8200000, 8300000, 8400000, 8500000, 8600000, 8700000, 8800000, 8900000, 9000000, 9100000, 9200000, 9300000, 9400000, 9500000, 9600000, 9700000, 9800000, 9900000, 10000000];
var slider = $("#slider-range-price").slider({
    orientation: 'horizontal',
    range: true,
    step: .0001,
    min: 50000,
    max: 10000000,
    animate: "slow",
    values: [0, 10000000],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var includeLeft = event.keyCode != $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT;
        var includeRight = event.keyCode != $.ui.keyCode.LEFT;
        var value = findNearest(includeLeft, includeRight, ui.value);
        if (ui.value == ui.values[0]) {
            slider.slider('values', 0, value);
        } else {
            slider.slider('values', 1, value);
        }
        // $("#price-amount").html();
        var min = kFormatter(slider.slider('values', 0));
        var max = kFormatter(slider.slider('values', 1));

        $('input[name="input_20"]').val('$' + min + ' - $' + max);
        $("#slider-range-price span:nth-child(2)").html("<div class='min-price-sales'>" + min + "</div>");
        $("#slider-range-price span:nth-child(3)").html("<div class='min-price-sales'>" + max + "</div>");
        return false;
    }

});
```

I have the code above, its a JUQERY UI slider with specific values, its all working. But as you can see the `values` which is up to `10,000,000`with following intervals is too long. Is it possible to shorten this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a loop to push a number to an array, and increment by either `50000` or `100000`, depending on the current value:

```js
var values = [];
for (let num = 50000; num <= 10000000; num += (num <= 950000 ? 50000 : 100000)) {
  values.push(num);
}

console.log(values);
```